# MediaPlayer через URI - воспроизвести из внешней памяти

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer, uri

Аудиофайл хранится в телефоне. Я хочу его воспроизвести. 
Я получаю URI файла, после того, как пользователь выбрал его

`uri.getPath();` показывает

`/TREE/PRIMATY:VLAD/1.mp3` или `/DOCUMENT/PRIMATY:VLAD/1.mp3`

как воспроизвести этот файл в MediaPlayer? как указать путь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MediaPlayer` умеет работать непосредственно с `Uri`:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);
```

или

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(context, uri);
```

Comment: *facepalm* я пробовал, но не получалось. сейчас все вышло.