# Uri to FilePath и наоборот

Tags: java, android, uri

**СИТУАЦИЙ №1**

Есть `Uri uri`. Он хорошо работает, музыка играет через плеер с него. но когда я пытаюсь через `uri` обратиться к самому файлу, то у меня ничего не выходит. `file.exists()` возвращает `false`.

```
uri = data.getData();
           Log.e("f", "" + uri);      //     E/f: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AVLAD%2F1.mp3
            mus = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, uri);
            mus.start(); // музыка iграе, дзеуки пяюць

 File fl = new File(uri.getPath());  // я понимаю, что тут ошибка
            Log.e("we  ", "" + fl.exists() + "    " + fl.getPath());     //    E/we: false    /document/primary:VLAD/1.mp3
```

**СИТАЦИЯ №2**

Этот же аудио-файл берем через File через Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). файл существует, все отлично. пытаемся сделать из него uri, но плеер не хочет его воспроизводить.

```
 File fl = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/VLAD/1.mp3");
                Log.e("f   ", "" + fl.exists()); //   E/f: true
                Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fl);
                Log.e("f   ", "" + u); // E/f: file:///storage/emulated/0/VLAD/1.mp3
                mus = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, u);
                mus.start();
```

Ошибка

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
```

Нужно решения для обоих случаев. Гугл уже не помогает.

Comment: Нет решения - все претензии к гуглу. На запрос контента имеет право ответить любое приложение и Андроид не предъявляет никаких требований, ни к составлению Uri-строки, ни к данным, которые приложение должно по этому Uri возвращать - всё на усмотрение разработчика. Поэтому можете считать, что получить путь к файлу через Uri невозможно. Есть конечно костыль, примерно на сотню строк, который охватывает некоторое количество известных случаев, но полагаться на "авось попадёт" не советую.

Comment: @woesss та ну... если вернуться к вопросу, что вы сегодня мне помогли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1069742/mediaplayer-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-uri-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8 как тогда воспроизвести File в MediaPlayer ?

Comment: @woesss или к этому https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1069320/%d0%a3%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5 как тогда получить сразу FilePath папки, которую пользователь сам укажет через Intent ?

Comment: *как тогда воспроизвести File в MediaPlayer* - если проблема в этом, то `mus = new MediaPlayer(); mus.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());` и, естественно, права на `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` должны быть уже получены. Скорее всего и в вашем примере проблема именно в отсутствии прав.